# How to specify path to the installed tool?

Tags: command-line, paths, tools

I have installed [SRA Toolkit](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/s/sra-toolkit/install/index.html) using this command `sudo apt-get install sra-toolkit` under ubuntu. Now I am trying to use one of it's part - `fastq-dump.2.1.7` but I receive an error from which I understoodthat I didn't specify path to that software. This is weird because I can check the version of this software and it is also added to `/usr/bin/` directory. Does anyone know how to overcome this error? Code is below

```
mkosinski@mkosinski-E540:~$ fastq-dump.2.1.7 ~/WCO/Kasia/SRR1294095.sra 
2015-10-19T20:52:13 fastq-dump.2.1.7 err: path incorrect while opening manager within database module - failed /home/mkosinski/WCO/Kasia/SRR1294095.sra
Written 0 spots total
mkosinski@mkosinski-E540:~$ fastq-dump.2.1.7 -version

fastq-dump.2.1.7 : 2.1.7

mkosinski@mkosinski-E540:~$ ls  -l /usr/bin/fastq-dump.2.1.7 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 93384 cze 15  2012 /usr/bin/fastq-dump.2.1.7
```

Comment: That looks like an issue specific to `fastq-dump`, I doubt it is an issue with how it was installed.  `fastq-dump` is actually working but can't access its internal database. You would be better off asking on a site that specializes on bioinformatics. Try http://biostars.org, for example. I doubt we'll be able to help you here. Also, please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33211734/1081936) on multiple sites of the SE network.

Comment: Tried to post there: https://www.biostars.org/p/162483/#162526

Comment: Great. If you do get an answer there, it would be nice if you could remember to come and post it here.

Comment: Received and posted :)

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/162483/#162526
It was a problem with `.sra` file - not with the `SRA Toolkit`.